# How to use two aggregations from one table to calculate a metric in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table named TRANSACTION, that has the following columns:

```
ITEM
STORE
REASON
QUANTITY
```

I need to calculate a metric, "30_DAYS_SALES_QUANTITY" as per the following calculation:-

30_DAYS_SALES_QUANTITY = (Aggregated SUM of QUANTITY by ITEM, STORE when REASON = 183) - (Aggregated SUM of QUANTITY by ITEM, STORE when REASON = 182)
BETWEEN SYSDATE - 30 and SYSDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [CASE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) statement

```
SELECT ITEM, STORE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN REASON = 183 THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END)-
    SUM(CASE WHEN REASON = 182 THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END)
FROM TRANSACTION
GROUP BY ITEM, STORE
```